# Access groovy variable inside shell and perform arithmetic operations on them

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to perform arithmatic operation by accessing variable and modifying it.

Its giving error as Bad substitution

```
env.SUCCESSFUL_DEPLOY=$((${env.SUCCESSFUL_DEPLOY} + 1))
```

Can anyone suggest how to make it work

```
 stages {
        stage('my stage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    ansiColor('xterm') {
                        echo ""
                    }
                    try {
                        env.SUCCESSFUL_DEPLOY = 0
                        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                         sh '''
                         echo "Hello"
                         if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
                            env.SUCCESSFUL_DEPLOY=$((${env.SUCCESSFUL_DEPLOY} + 1))
                         fi
                         '''
                         mymethod(env.AUTH_URL)
                        }
                        echo "Total successful deploys are :${env.SUCCESSFUL_DEPLOY} out of 3 deploys"
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        echo $err
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit 1:
As per suggestion used like

```
                    try {
                        env.SUCCESSFUL_DEPLOY = 0
                        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        sh """
                        echo 'Hello'
                        if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
                           env.SUCCESSFUL_DEPLOY=${ env.SUCCESSFUL_DEPLOY + 1 }
                        fi
                        """
                        }
                        echo "Total successful deploys are :${env.SUCCESSFUL_DEPLOY} out of 3 deploys"
                    }
```

But it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using one `$` too much. This should work.

```
env.SUCCESSFUL_DEPLOY=${ env.SUCCESSFUL_DEPLOY + 1 }
```

Besides the string interpolation I noticed that you are using `$?` to find out the last exit code. Are you aware you can use `returnStatus: true` in order to recieve the exit code from the `sh` function?

Edit: I just noticed you are using `'''`, change those to `"""`

Comment: This is not working. Still getting bad substitution error and yes I am aware of `returnStatus: true` but since I am using multi-line sh I can use that

Comment: You need to use double quotes, see the edit in my answer